# Basic passport.js signup function fails, thinks username has already been taken

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm using passport.js to get a basic signup function established for a Node + Express + Sequelize app. Right now I have an empty database, and am using just the passport-local strategy to get the user's email and password from a form, check this against the database to ensure the email is not associated with another account, and then once this has been established, create the user.

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

### ./config/passport.js

```
const db = require('./sequelize');
const passport = require('passport'), 
 LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    db.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    emailField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
    }, 
    function(email, password, done){
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            db.User.findOne({ email : email }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(null, false, {message: err});
                // check to see if there's already a user with that email
                else if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'User already exists'});
                } 
                else {
                    return done(null, true, {message: 'User created'});
                }
            });    
        });
     }
));

module.exports = passport;
```

### app.js

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
        const user = req.body;
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        if (err){ 
            res.send({success: false, message: 'authentication failed'}); 
        } 
        if (!user) {
            console.log(user);
            res.send({message: "user already found"});
        }

        else{
            db.User.create({
                email: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password
            });
            console.log(info);
            res.json({message: "user successfully signed up"});
        }
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

### ./config/sequelize

```
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const _         = require('lodash');
const config    = require('./config');
const db        = {};

// create your instance of sequelize
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.name, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    port: config.db.port,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    storage: config.db.storage
});

//Instantiate the database

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(function(err) {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    }, function (err) { 
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

/* this is where all of the MODELS will be defined for the time being */

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING
});

sequelize.sync();

db.User = User;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;


module.exports = db;
```

However, when I run the app with the clean database, !user in the app.js file evaluates to false, and I am unable to sign up new users because it would seem to be that the strategy thinks there is already an existing user with that email in the database. What do I need to do to remedy situation?

Comment: I cannot understand the logic behing responding that user exists in case !user condition is fulfilled. As far as I understand you purpose, your condition contains an unnecessary "!".

Comment: I deleted that if statement and made the changes suggested by alexi2 and now my signup function is (unfortunately) able to insert multiple users of the same email address

Answer (score 0):

```
db.User.findOne({ where: { email : email }})
.then(
    function(user) {
      if (user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'User already exists'});
      } else {
        return done(null, true, {message: 'User created'});
    );
```

Comment: I implemented this change but now I'm able to enter multiple users with the same email address. Do you think this error pertains to the LocalStrategy params passwordField and emailField?

Comment: Now none of the signups (distinct email or non-distinct) work, and console.info yields "Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`,
`updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` LIMIT 1;"

Comment: Good catch, but we're still back to square one with allowing multiple non-distinct usernames to be inserted

Comment: Update to use promises, I am fairly certain you can add a catch for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code

using redirects here (**app.js**):

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/profile',
    failureRedirect : '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

using promises for sequelize queries (**./config/passport.js**):

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.User.findById(id).then(function(user) {
    done(err, user.dataValues);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
   emailField : 'email',
   passwordField : 'password',
   passReqToCallback : true
}, 
function(req, email, password, done){
    process.nextTick(function() {
        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        db.User.findOne({ where: {email : email }})
        .then(function(user) {
            if (user !== null) {
                done(null, false, {message: 'User already exists'});
            } 
            else {
              db.User.create({ 
                email: email,
                password: password
              })
              .then(function(user){
                done(null, user);
              })
              .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
                done(null, false);
              });
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            return done(null, false, {message: err});
        });    
    });
   }
));
```